# Why does my runOnUiThread not work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why does this not work in my aSyncTask? My app crashes.
I'm trying to update my list from a mysql table

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            // dismiss dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();      
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    // Add adapter to the list
                    MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(Albums.this, itemList);
                    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);   
                    }
                });

        }
```

---

LogCat:

```
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.example.whs.Albums$LoadAllItems.onPostExecute(Albums.java:149)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.example.whs.Albums$LoadAllItems.onPostExecute(Albums.java:1)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-28 18:21:09.013: E/AndroidRuntime(10600):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is where i make the itemList from the mysql table.

```
items = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);

                    // loop through the items
                    for (int i = 0; items.length() > i; i++){
                        // Get the item in variable c
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Store in a variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        if(username == ""){
                            username = "onbekend";
                        }

                        // Create the HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // add it
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(THUMBNAIL, "updates");

                        // to arraylist
                        itemList.add(map);                      
                    }
```

What id should i use for the listview, i have "@android:id/list"

edit: Here is the latest log after using Albums.this.getListView();

```
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at com.example.whs.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:58)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1428)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2000)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1821)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1118)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4550)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-28 18:35:10.718: E/AndroidRuntime(23103):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.example.whs.Albums$LoadAllItems.onPostExecute(Albums.java:149)` What is line 149? Does your layout have a ListView with this id?

Comment: that is list.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: Ok, double check your layout because it doesn't have a ListView with that id. Did you mean `android.R.id.list`?

Comment: @Stumpje : if you are extending ListActivity then either use `ListView list=Albums.this.getListView()` or make sure u have ListView it `@android:id/list` as in xml layout if you are using custom layout and find it as `ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Comment: @Stumpje :`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` just check size of ArrayList you are passing to Adapter before accessing elements from it

Comment: arraysize = 21, just checked it

Comment: @Stumpje : which is line 58 in MenuAdapter.java?

Comment: int identifier = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(menuThumbnailArray[position], "drawable", activity.getPackageName());

Comment: So `menuThumbnailArray[position]` only has two values, but the log shows you are trying to read a third... Please post your entire `getView()` method (or your entire Adapter).

Comment: yep, and it is fixed now. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What id should i use for the listview, i have "@android:id/list"

You need to use `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`, since it is in the Android namespace unlike a regular id `"@id/list"` where you simply use `findViewById(R.id.list)`.

---

**Addition**
This new error is probably in your MenuAdapter's `getCount()` method but I know it crashes in `getView()`...  How do I know?  Let's walk through the LogCat:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
    at com.example.whs.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:58)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
```

The line on top is the exception, you are trying to read a value that doesn't exist in an Array. The next line shows the last place your code ran and where the error was thrown.  `MenuAdapter.java:58` is the file name and line number, for a bonus it tells you the method name too: `getView()`.  The only Array used in a typical Adapter is the one you passed to the constructor...

Comment: Post the new LogCat errors in your question, but we cannot help you every time the app crashes... So I'll teach you how to read this new stack trace so you can hunt these errors down faster.

Comment: @Stumpje : simply use `ListView list=Albums.this.getListView()` if you are extending ListActivity to Albums class  and if not working then add latest log with question

Comment: i cant override that method, is that a problem?

Answer (score 4):

Because [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) is always invoked on the UI Thread, there is no need to use `runOnUiThread` for accessing or updating UI elements in onPostExecute. Change your code as:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            // dismiss dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();      

            // access or update UI here without runOnUiThread

        }
```

Comment: +1, Also the author shouldn't need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on a new Adapter.

Comment: @Stumpje : as sam comment `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` line causing issue

Comment: I think `notifyDataSetChanged()` is redundant, but not the error. I'm guessing `list` is the problem...

Comment: @Stumpje : where u are adding elements in itemList ArrayList ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `runOnUiThread()` redundant?  `onPostExecute()` is already running on the UI thread, you should not need it.  Try taking it out and see what happens!

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @Stumpje Are you initializing `itemList` properly somewhere?  Also, are you sure that there is not problem with `R.id.list`?